# Why is this revelation about the Ancient One significant?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange-2016, doctor-strange

In the Doctor Strange movie, we learn towards the end of the movie that

> the Ancient One used the spell described on the page that Kaecilius stole to obtain eternal life.

However, after that reveal, it seems to be completely forgotten. In particular, we don't know

> why she even used it (I guess eternal life is motivation enough, but wise people would be more cautious), why she changed her mind about using that spell after that, or why she even could attain eternal life while despising the “big baddy” of the movie, when Mikkelsen's character didn't.

Therefore: **what is the point of that reveal?** It seems completely unconsenquential for the story told. Did I miss something?

Comment: “after that reveal, it seems to be completely forgotten” — er, [Mordo doesn’t forget it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Strange_(film)#Plot).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The reveal in question tells us that;

> The Ancient One's lengthy life is attributed to her using magic and energy from the Dark Dimension, the place where the evil Dormammu lives. She claims that she does this so that she can continue to protect the world, but there is an implication that the world is only in danger in the first place specifically *because* she uses magic and energy from the Dark Dimension.

This reveal shows us that regardless of her intentions for why she did it, she is a hypocrite, which Kaecilius calls her at the start of the movie. This is the reason that Kaecilius and his followers abandoned her, which helps us further understand the motivations of the films villains.

Maybe more importantly, it also undermines Karl Mordo's faith in The Ancient One and the teachings he has learned. This results in

> him abandoning Strange and Wong at the end of the movie, setting him up to be a villain further on down the line.

As such, the reveal also helps further develop the character of Karl Mordo.

Comment: Mmm... I don't remember the implication you mention. Is it stated by any character? Mordo? It's been a while since I watched the movie.

Comment: @AndresF. It's the reason for Kaecilius' rebellion, and why he calls her a hypocrite at the start of the film.